# Custom filename extension handler in Twisted webserver for template rendering

Tags: python, django-templates, webserver, jinja2, twisted

I have a twisted web server with static files served in an htdocs/... hierarchy. I would like to pass all .template files to mako/jinja before returning them, but return non-templated static files directly. Does anyone have any insight on the best way to do this? I would like to avoid having to put them in a *specific directory* instead I would like to leave them in the natural file hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted to use a file processor, but in the end I ended up subclassing static.File and overriding the render() method. The only complication was that I didn't realize that my type (MakoFile) would be instantiated for each child - this was causing me to lose my local mako context at times. In the end I realize the each instance of the File class has a Registry() handed down.

So I subclassed Registry as MakoRegistry, stuck my template lookup and context in there and pushed it into the top level object. This is working so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a "processor" and then direct Twisted Web to use it.  For example, if you're using `twistd web` to run your web server:

```
twistd web --processor template=yourlib.JinjaProcessor
```

If you're not using `twistd web`, you can use this functionality by populating the `processors` attribute of a `twisted.web.static.File` that represents a parent directory of the `.template` files.

A processor is just a callable that takes a `FilePath` and returns an `IResource` provider.

Comment: This works but I couldn't figure out how to make index.html be index.mako (if it exists), so handling / became impossible

Comment: `static.File` also has an `indexNames` attribute.  `indexNames = ["index.mako"]` would probably do it (or you could append that name instead of replacing others if you prefer).  Also, there's `ignoredExts` which you could make include `".mako"` and then a request for `index` would find `index.mako` (if you want explicit index segments in your URL).